# vscode renderWhitespace with persian character

Tags: visual-studio-code, farsi

in visual studio code when you select **non-Unicode** characters while **renderWhitespace** feature is on , all selected non-Unicode characters become disordered.

**version**: 1.43.2

**OS**: windows 10

i'm looking for a solution to avoid from this annoying bug